# Confusion over multiple row subquery comparison

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm working in Oracle SQL Developer right now and am stumped on a query.  The prompt reads:
Provide an alphabetic listing of instructors who have never taught a course section.
List the salutation, first name, last name and zip code.

This is my current attempt:

```
SELECT i.Salutation, i.First_Name, i.Last_Name, i.Zip
FROM Instructor i
  JOIN Section s 
    ON i.Instructor_Id = s.Instructor_Id
WHERE 0 in (SELECT COUNT(Instructor_Id)
FROM Section 
GROUP BY Instructor_Id)
```

My code works (returns desired output for the instructors) when I search for instructors who actually have classes, but it doesn't recognize when I search for those with none.  I'm not too sure how to workaround this, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NOT EXISTS to get instructors that aren't in the Section table.

```
SELECT 
  Salutation,
  First_Name,
  Last_Name,
  Zip
FROM Instructor i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
 SELECT
  *
 FROM Section s
 WHERE i.Instructor_Id = s.Instructor_Id)
ORDER BY Last_Name
```

Comment: Ahh, I had no clue about this clause.  This makes sense and worked great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The default join is INNER, which means only rows from section where the instructor id matches are returned.  You probably want to specify LEFT OUTER JOIN [1].  The other common construct for this is to use WHERE NOT EXISTS [2]

[1] [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join/38578#38578)

[2] [NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)

Comment: Gotcha.  I need to make sure I'm familiar with how the joins work, thanks a ton. The Not Exists fixed this particular issue.

Comment: Yeah, you're gonna need to get friendly with INNER and LEFT OUTER joins at a minimum.  And get friendly with the concept of NULL and the surprising fact that NULL != NULL is false as well as NULL = NULL is false too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The following finds instructors who have never taught any courses.  Change the 'HAVING' clause condition to `> 0` to  get instructors who have taught some courses:

```
SELECT 
  i.Salutation,
  i.First_Name,
  i.Last_Name,
  i.Zip 
FROM Instructor i
left join section s
on i.instructor_id = s.instructor_id
group by 
i.instructor_id,
i.Salutation,
  i.First_Name,
  i.Last_Name,
  i.Zip  
having count(s.section_id)  = 0 /* > 0 if looking for instructors who have taught some courses */
order by i.last_name, i.first_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Get list of ID's from Section table for Instructors who have taught.  Use `NOT IN` to see who has not taught any classes.

```
SELECT i.Salutation, i.First_Name, i.Last_Name, i.Zip
FROM Instructor i
WHERE i.Instructor_Id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT s.Instructor_Id
    FROM Section
)
```